# read() output from execl command and print it using only write() syscall

Tags: c, fork, posix, pid

I am trying to execute `/bin/tar -tf` on a tar file with `execl()`. I would like it to read its contents and only print it to the terminal screen in my `main()` function with the `write()` syscall.

My code below somehow reads the contents and writes it to the terminal at the same time without having to resort to the write() syscall to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int pfd[2];

// Problem 1:
// ERROR : read() function reads and writes to the terminal.
// I would like to write the contents of the 'buffer' variable with the
// write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) syscall to the terminal preferably
// in the main() function.
// Problem 2:
// is the 'status' variable along with the _exit function useful here?
// I am not sure if a pipe is needed?
int show_tar(pid_t *pid, char *buffer, int *bytes_read, char **tar_name)
{
    int status = 0;
    pipe(pfd);
    if ((*pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(0, pfd[0]);
        execl("/bin/tar", "tar", "-tf", tar_name[1], (char *)NULL);
    } else {
        close(pfd[1]);
        *bytes_read = read(pfd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        wait(NULL);
    }
    _exit(status);
    return status;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int bytes_read = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    int status = show_tar(&pid, buffer, &bytes_read, argv);
    wait(&status);
    // write contents of 'buffer' to the terminal with the
    // write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) function like so:
    // int ch;
    // while (1) {
    //     if ((ch = getchar()) == 27) // Press <Escape> to quit program
    //         break;
    //     else  
    //         write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    // }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed on Linux with `argv[1]` being the tarball:

```
gcc buffer.c -o buffer && ./buffer "$HOME/<your tarball>.tar.gz"
```

The output shows the entire contents of the tarball without having to resort to the `write()` syscall.

Comment: `tar` writes to `stdout`.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: Also make sure you handle the error case when one of the `exec*()` family of functions returns.  It only returns on an error; there's no need to test the return value.  But you should normally at least exit with a non-zero status; often, you should write a message about the failure to standard error and then exit.  Whether to use `exit()` or `_exit()` can get fraught — using `_exit()` is often (usually) OK, and using `exit()` is sometimes a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This needed a great deal of work, and it's still not really there, but this ought to get you started.

I think you have your pipes a little confused: they are a one-way channel, and anything written on `pfd[1]` can be read on `pfd[0]`, so they're not using the pipe properly.

Parent and child should always close the "other" end of the pipe they are not using, and you have to arrange so that the write-pipe is literally number 1 (stdout).

```
int show_tar(pid_t *pid, char *buffer, int *bytes_read, char **tar_name)
{
    int status = 0;
    int buffer_size = *bytes_read;  // pass IN the buffer size
    int pfd[2];
    pipe(pfd);
    if ((*pid = fork()) == 0) {
        close(pfd[0]);  // child doesn't need read pipe
        dup2(pfd[1], 1); // insure write pipe is at stdout (fd#1)
        dup2(pfd[1], 2); // stderr goes to the pipe also (optional)
        close(pfd[1]);  // child doesn't need write pipe any more
        execl("/bin/tar", "tar", "-tf", tar_name[1], (char *)NULL);
        _exit(1);
    } else {
        close(pfd[1]);  // parent doesn't need write pipe
        *bytes_read = read(pfd[0], buffer, buffer_size);

        // insure NUL byte at the end
        if (*bytes_read >= 0) buffer[*bytes_read] = 0;

        wait(NULL);
    }
//  _exit(status);    // we don't need this!
    return status;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int bytes_read = sizeof buffer;
    pid_t pid;

    int status = show_tar(&pid, buffer, &bytes_read, argv);
    wait(&status);

    // print the value here
    return 0;
}
```

This somewhat oversimplifies the pipe descriptor management, because if this is being run in an environment where stdin/stdout are already closed, then the pipe might actually use fd#0 and fd#1.

In the end you sometimes have to do tricky things by checking for file descriptors to see if they are already what you want, and `dup`ing around clashes. But if run from a terminal session, this is fine to get started.

ALSO: be aware that the standard error stream (fd#2) is still connected to the original terminal, so things like error messages from `tar` will not be captured by this mechanism. Again, more tricky pipe descriptor management.

EDIT: I just noticed that all paths in `show_tar()` flow through `_exit()`, so it will never return.

EDIT: move the definition of `int pfd[2];` to *inside* `show_tar()` - it doesn't need to be at file scope.

EDIT: just realized that `sizeof(buffer)` in `show_tar()` is not doing what you think; the size of the pointer is always 4 or 8 (depending on platform), not the number of bytes available - this would have to be passed as a parameter. I've overloaded the `*bytes_read` parameter to pass *in* the # of bytes available, and you already are using it to pass *back* the number read.

The parent must also loop, reading bytes from the pipe until it gets end-of-file because it's unlikely that everything from `tar` will go in a single read.

Comment: I wrote a paper many years ago on getting pipes right, maybe this will help.

http://unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pipe-fds.html